# How to reference same column name but different table in custom db query

Tags: query, wpdb

I use `wpdb` to connect to a custom db, then I use the following query:

```
$my_row = $wpdb_c->get_results(
  "SELECT Employee.Name, Area.Name, Area.Region"
  . " FROM Area INNER JOIN Employee ON Area.ID = Employee.Area_ID"
  . " WHERE Employee.ID = " . get_the_ID()
);
```

How do I refer to each of the `Name` columns from the `Employee` and `Area` tables? I tried `$my_row[0]->Area.Name` but it only returned the string `'Name'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your query and use the SQL  alias `as`:

```
$my_row = $wpdb_c->get_results("SELECT Employee.Name as Employe_Name, Area.Name as 
Area_Name, Area.Region as Area_Region FROM Area INNER JOIN Employee ON Area.ID = 
Employee.Area_ID WHERE Employee.ID = " . get_the_ID());
```

Then in your code use:

```
$my_row[0]->Area_Name
```

Comment: sweet, i actually did this while waiting for an answer. man, so i can't use the `table.column`? i'll have to be aware of that, then. thanks again, @keatch